# calculate conjugate momentum p for a lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics

For the Lagrangian  $2L=\dot{q}^2-q\dot{q}+q^2$

(A) $q+\dot{q}$

(B) $q-\dot{q}$

(C) $q\dot{q}$

(D) $\dot{q}-q$

I have a doubt here. in fiew books $p$ is said to be generalized momentum. Does these generalized momentum and conjugate momentums are same? If yes the by definition

$p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q} }= \dot{q}-\frac{q}{2}$. In that case all the four given options are wrong.

Comment: Generalized and conjugate momenta are indeed synonyms. Your derivation is correct. I suspect that your reference meant $2L = \dot{q}^2 - 2q\dot{q} + q^2$ instead.

Comment: I think so. Thank you for the clarification